Next.js - Module with private modules
I want to create a component (X) in Next.js (with Typescript) that I will use in the /app directory.
The component X consists of other components, which should only be used by X. The subcomponents should not be visible in the /app directory.
File structure:
src/
  app/
    page.tsx
  components/
    X/
      x.tsx
      internal/
        y.tsx
        z.tsx

Is that possible or how would you solve it? It is important that the components y.tsx and z.tsx can only be consumed by x.tsx.
